# convert string consisting of individual numbers and sequences to format which allows subsetting a vector or dataframe

Tags: r, string, indexing

my problem refers to converting a string consisting of both individual numbers and sequences to a format, which allows me to subset a vector or dataframe. Background: The string originates from a cell in a .csv, which is read in as configuration-file and should be used for subsetting certain elements of a dataframe automatically/without typing it manually like my_vec[c(1,5,10:13,90)]. The sticking point is the sequence within the individual numbers. Otherwise a strsplit() by "," would deliver the desired result.

`subsetting_string<-"1,5,10:13,90"`

I want this string/character to be able to subset for example a vector from 1 to 100

`my_vec<-seq(1,100,1)`

to receive the result

`[1] 1 5 10 11 12 13 90`

Important: I´m not looking for the following procedure, I already know:

`my_vec[c(1,5,10:20,90)]`

But how can I convert/process the string (character) to be directly used as indexing element within the [] brackets? I had lots of tries with sub(), substr(), strsplit(), paste() and noquote(), but I always failed up to now.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may split (`strsplit`) by comma (`,`) and loop over each of the elements with `lapply/sapply`, do an `eval`uation and `unlist` to create a vector

```
ind <- unlist(sapply(strsplit(subsetting_string, ",")[[1]], 
    function(x) eval(parse(text = x))), use.names = FALSE)
```

-output

```
> ind
[1]  1  5 10 11 12 13 90
```

Comment: thank you, akrun, this is what I was looking for. Never dealt with expressions and the evaluation of them before, but now I see, that I need to in some situations. Thanks for your early reply!